# VOIP call integration in ios

Tags: ios, voip, ios10, xcode8

I am new for VOIP call integration in swift language. Is there any framework without any payment require for VOIP integration? 
I try this link :- https://github.com/jconst/PhoneKit using Twilio Client Server
Can any one give me Voip call without any charges or voip call integration in detail

Comment: I don't think VOIP call possible without any charges!

Comment: VOIP call possible without any charges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sinch Framework SDK. Sinch allows developers to quickly and easily add voice, instant messaging and SMS features to their apps, using their SDK and REST API. You can use this link for VOIP implementation https://www.sinch.com/

Comment: It's also paid.

Comment: No, It's fee of cost.

Comment: sinch gives free credits just for testing various services.. later you need to pay

Answer (score 6):

You can setup your own VOIP architecture.

This is totally free of cost setup.

VOIP is just protocol, your server person can make it and provide you VOIP channel URL ( Absolute URL ).

Basically it is WebRTC, Real Time Communication.

Only your server maintenance cost will occur.

https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-server

Comment: i am having a taxi app like uber, i want a trip request page currently we are using FCM but it is not opening the app when closed . I want to open the app using VOIP but don't need any other functionalities only accepting the call is required is it possible

Comment: This is doable with normal push notification ( FCM ) as well. You can also utilise pushkit ( Voip ) , refer pushkit kit integration here https://github.com/hasyapanchasara

Comment: @Hasya I have setup my WebRTC with socket. Can you guide me further? I want to have voice call in my app. All webRTC examples provides video calling.